# How to create new list of dicts in python by consolidating dicts in another list?

Tags: python

In Python, I have a list of dicts as follows:

```
orig_list = [
{'first_name': u'Jake', 'last_name': u'Sarson', 'team': u'TeamOne', 
 'display_name': u'AVG', 'value': 7.0},

{'first_name': u'Mike', 'last_name': u'Walsh', 'team': u'TeamTwo', 
 'display_name': u'AVG', 'value': 12.0},

{'first_name': u'Jake', 'last_name': u'Sarson', 'team': u'TeamOne', 
 'display_name': u'AVG', 'value': 7.0},

{'first_name': u'Mike', 'last_name': u'Walsh', 'team': u'TeamTwo', 
 'display_name': u'AVG', 'value': 12.0},

{'first_name': u'Steve', 'last_name': u'Mottola', 'team': u'TeamTwo', 
 'display_name': u'AVG', 'value': 18.0},

{'first_name': u'Steve', 'last_name': u'Mottola', 'team': u'TeamTwo', 
 'display_name': u'AVG', 'value': 18.0},

{'first_name': u'Craig', 'last_name': u'Schubert', 'team': u'TeamOne', 
 'display_name': u'AVG', 'value': 23.5},

{'first_name': u'Steve', 'last_name': u'Mottola', 'team': u'TeamTwo', 
 'display_name': u'REC', 'value': 2.0},

{'first_name': u'Mike', 'last_name': u'Walsh', 'team': u'TeamTwo', 
 'display_name': u'REC', 'value': 1.0},

{'first_name': u'Jake', 'last_name': u'Sarson', 'team': u'TeamOne', 
 'display_name': u'REC', 'value': 1.0},

{'first_name': u'Craig', 'last_name': u'Schubert', 'team': u'TeamOne', 
 'display_name': u'REC', 'value': 2.0},

{'first_name': u'Craig', 'last_name': u'Schubert', 'team': u'TeamOne', 
 'display_name': u'TD', 'value': 1.0},

{'first_name': u'Steve', 'last_name': u'Mottola', 'team': u'TeamTwo', 
 'display_name': u'YDS', 'value': 36.0},

{'first_name': u'Jake', 'last_name': u'Sarson', 'team': u'TeamOne', 
 'display_name': u'YDS', 'value': 7.0},

{'first_name': u'Mike', 'last_name': u'Walsh', 'team': u'TeamTwo', 
 'display_name': u'YDS', 'value': 12.0},

{'first_name': u'Craig', 'last_name': u'Schubert', 'team': u'TeamOne', 
 'display_name': u'YDS', 'value': 47.0}]
```

I need to create a new list of dicts from the first list to find the unique names and for each name find all the display_name's and the values. In essence the result should be:

```
[{'first_name': u'Jake', 'last_name': u'Sarson', 'team': u'TeamOne', 
  'AVG': 7.0, 'REC': 1.0, 'YDS': 7.0},
{'first_name': u'Mike', 'last_name': u'Walsh',  'team': u'TeamTwo',
  'AVG': 12.0, 'REC': 1.0, 'YDS': 12.0},
{'first_name': u'Steve', 'last_name': u'Mottola', 'team': u'TeamTwo',
  'AVG': 18.0, 'REC': 2.0, 'YDS': 36.0},
{'first_name': u'Craig', 'last_name': u'Schubert', 'team': u'TeamOne', 
  'AVG': 23.5, 'REC': 2.0, 'TD': 1.0, 'YDS': 47.0}]
```

I tried with nested for loops but kept getting an error that the "dict is unhashable." What is the best solution for this data structure?

Comment: Did you read about the dictionary `update` method yet?   If not, please read that and revise your question.

Comment: Thank you. I will read up on the update method. The python docs sometimes don't help me all the time and only if I see an example do I understand.

Comment: "only if I see an example do I understand"  Perhaps you should find a way to get past this.  Python documentation is an excellent resource, and you'd able to solve problems more quickly if you could find a way to read them.

Comment: @simi: I suggest that you take your time and play with `dict`s a bit more in order to understand how they work. You have asked a few questions about them already, so you obviously need to improve there.

Comment: Thank you again. I will try harder and play around with dicts more. Learning is not fun when it becomes frustrating.

Comment: @simi: "Learning is not fun". Perhaps you should find a way to get past this.  In my experience life is learning.  If it's not fun, you should perhaps find a way to make it fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
temp = {}
for rec in orig_list:
    temp.setdefault((rec['first_name'], rec['last_name'], rec['team']), {}).setdefault(rec['display_name'], rec['value'])

persons = []
for key, person in temp.iteritems():
    person.update(dict(zip(('first_name', 'last_name', 'team'), key)))
    persons.append(person)
```

Comment: Thank you eumiro. This does give me the output I want. I will read up on update and setdefault to understand how it all works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got using collections.defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
j = defaultdict(dict)
for player in origlist:
 j[(player['first_name'],player['last_name'],player['team'])].update({player['display_name']: player['value']})
```

This gives me the following output for j.items():

```
[((u'Mike', u'Walsh', u'TeamTwo'), {u'AVG': 12.0, u'REC': 1.0, u'YDS': 12.0}),
 ((u'Jake', u'Sarson', u'TeamOne'), {u'AVG': 7.0, u'REC': 1.0, u'YDS': 7.0}),
 ((u'Steve', u'Mottola', u'TeamTwo'),
  {u'AVG': 18.0, u'REC': 2.0, u'YDS': 36.0}),
 ((u'Craig', u'Schubert', u'TeamOne'),
  {u'AVG': 23.5, u'REC': 2.0, u'TD': 1.0, u'YDS': 47.0})]
```

From the j.items() then I go build the final list:

```
nl0 = []
for k,v in j.items():
    o = {'first_name': k[0], 'last_name': k[1], 'team': k[2]}
    o.update(v)
    nl0.append(o)
    o = {}
```

And the result is what I need:

```
[{u'AVG': 12.0,
  u'REC': 1.0,
  u'YDS': 12.0,
  'first_name': u'Mike',
  'last_name': u'Walsh',
  'team': u'TeamTwo'},
 {u'AVG': 7.0,
  u'REC': 1.0,
  u'YDS': 7.0,
  'first_name': u'Jake',
  'last_name': u'Sarson',
  'team': u'TeamOne'},
 {u'AVG': 18.0,
  u'REC': 2.0,
  u'YDS': 36.0,
  'first_name': u'Steve',
  'last_name': u'Mottola',
  'team': u'TeamTwo'},
 {u'AVG': 23.5,
  u'REC': 2.0,
  u'TD': 1.0,
  u'YDS': 47.0,
  'first_name': u'Craig',
  'last_name': u'Schubert',
  'team': u'TeamOne'}]
```

Is this a good example of how to use collections.defaultdict?